# Link travis-ci.com, travis-ci.org accounts

Tags: account, travis-ci

Is it possible to link accounts at travis-ci.com and travis-ci.org? Both use the same github account to sign in, and it'd be great not to have to switch back and forth in order to look at my various repos.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about user administration on a specific website, rather than programming or programming tools. -edit- Wait... Travis redirects *all* questions to SO?

Comment: Yes, I agree. I'd prefer to ask on a real FAQ/Q&A/Help site run by Travis, but this is all I've got.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this currently isn't possible, but it's something we have on our roadmap to change in the coming months.

Comment: Any news on this? And is it possible to run public repos on pro infra to avoid the afternoon super slowness?